# URL rewrite in IIS 8.5 is not working I'm getting 404 instead

Tags: iis, rewrite, iis-8.5

Hi I've configured a rewrite rule on my IIS but it seems like it never gets fired I've been working on this for several hours without any luck this is my rule:

my URL is the following:

http://localhost:2934/trabajos/3ba2a9e4/some-cool-title
'
and I want ro rewrite to
http://localhost:2934/snapshots/3ba2a9e4.html

this is the result I get from the IIs when testing the pattern:

[image: tesing URL rewrite iis]

but I feel like the rule never gets fired, in fact, I've configured to trace failed request like [this tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) and I don't get any error or file in the logs folder.
ex: C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

I'm getting a 404 error instead and it's logged like this:

```
2015-03-28 18:56:11 ::1 GET /trabajos/3ba2a9e4/some-cool-tile - 2934 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/42.0.2311.60+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 4
2015-03-28 18:56:15 ::1 GET /trabajos/3ba2a9e4/some-cool-title - 2934 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/42.0.2311.60+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 2
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You Can solve this issue by following this.
[image]

Alternatively:

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(trabajos)/(3ba2a9e4)/(some-cool-title)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP-HOST}/snapshots/{R:2}.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```